# Specifying the Discriminator Value using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent

The default for `DiscriminatorValue` is the fully qualified name of the `Subclass`.

I'd like to map this to a number e.g an enum value, or a single character. I have tried specifying it within the mapping using the `DiscriminatorValue` however that has no impact and it sticks with the subclass name.

Example:

```
public class MovieMapping : SubclassMap<Movie>
{
    public MovieMapping()
    {
        Map(m => m.Director);
        HasMany(m => m.Actors)
            .KeyColumn("MovieId")
            .AsList(l => l.Column("ActorIndex"));
        DiscriminatorValue("'M'");
    }
}
```

I would have expected to see `M` in the column for `Discriminator`, but it comes up with the fully qualified subclass name instead.

Any one else managed to do this with Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 2):

I was using DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn in the parent class. However the non generic version defaults to a string despite the subclasses indicating that they want integer values, and hence the type name string was getting stored.

I found a generic version of DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn, and once you use that it works fine and picks up the integer values for discriminator column.

DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("ProductType", (int)0);

I guess it may have helped if the mapping engine had thrown an error between the fact that the parent class has a string mapping, and the child class attempting to send an int value, but the mismatch was just getting ignored.